# How do I unhighlight text I just highlighted in Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

The error occurs as described in below steps:
1. If i search a keyword then the searched keyword is higlighted.
2.The next time i search something the previous search results that were highlighted remains.
3.How to remove the previous highlights that i made

```
 Private Sub Search_Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search_Button.Click

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application, currentDoc As Word.Document
    wordApp = DirectCast(GetObject(, "Word.Application"), Word.Application)

    currentDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument

    With currentDoc.Content.Find
        .MatchCase = False
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = SearchBox.Text

        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting()
            .Text = SearchBox.Text
            .Highlight = Word.WdColor.wdColorTurquoise
        End With
        .Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
    End With
End Sub

End Class
```

- I am learning to automate word using VB.NET. Are there any tutorials for beginners so please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (in reference to your code):

```
With currentDoc.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting()
    .Highlight = True

    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Highlight = False
'see additional comment below to this point of the code
    End With
    .Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
End With
```

Comment: sometimes it's required to add additional parameter(s) when working with `find >> replace`. If above presented syntax is not working try to add some (or all) of properties in the point I commented in the code above:

```
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
```

Comment: The word .Forward,.Wrap... gets `highlighted in blue color` giving error:'Forward' is not a member of' Word.Replacement',.Wrap is not a member of 'Word.Replacement...

Comment: yes, I gave you VBA code which you need to convert to VB.Net, I think this is a reason.